# InvalidPathException when selecting imported API for apikit:config

Tags: anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I'm new here and I have to ask a question when my Google searches were to no avail.

I'm using Anypoint-Studio for Mulesoft and am running into a problem. As the title states, I'm getting an InvalidPathException when selecting imported API for apikit:config. The values for the *api* attribute is automatically populated when I select my API. Please see more details below.

**flowfile.xml (apikit:config)**

```
<apikit:config outboundHeadersMapName="outboundHeadersMapName" httpStatusVarName="httpStatus" doc:name="Router" doc:id="480358cd-654a-4b61-8331-8cc74d1f0704" name="Router" api="resource::6e2fcd5a-6e44-4ffd-9766-303b81ab3fa6:sample-api:1.0.3:raml:zip:orgname/sample/exp.api/sample-api.raml" >
```

**Error**

```
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: org.mule.runtime.deployment.model.api.DeploymentInitException: InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 8: resource::6e2fcd5a-6e44-4ffd-9766-303b81ab3fa6:sample-api:1.0.3:raml:zip:orgname/sample/exp.api/sample-api.raml
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.deployment.model.api.DeploymentInitException: InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 8: resource::6e2fcd5a-6e44-4ffd-9766-303b81ab3fa6:sample-api:1.0.3:raml:zip:orgname/sample/exp.api/sample-api.raml
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.core.api.config.ConfigurationException: Illegal char <:> at index 8: resource::6e2fcd5a-6e44-4ffd-9766-303b81ab3fa6:sample-api:1.0.3:raml:zip:orgname/sample/exp.api/sample-api.raml
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Illegal char <:> at index 8: resource::6e2fcd5a-6e44-4ffd-9766-303b81ab3fa6:sample-api:1.0.3:raml:zip:orgname/sample/exp.api/sample-api.raml
Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 8: resource::6e2fcd5a-6e44-4ffd-9766-303b81ab3fa6:sample-api:1.0.3:raml:zip:orgname/sample/exp.api/sample-api.raml
at org.mule.module.apikit.Configuration.initialise(Configuration.java:110) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.lifecycle.LifecycleUtils.initialiseIfNeeded(LifecycleUtils.java:52) ~[mule-core-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.func.CheckedConsumer.accept(CheckedConsumer.java:19) ~[mule-core-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:115) ~[mule-core-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.lifecycle.phases.MuleContextInitialisePhase.applyLifecycle(MuleContextInitialisePhase.java:69) ~[mule-core-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.SpringRegistryLifecycleManager$SpringContextInitialisePhase.applyLifecycle(SpringRegistryLifecycleManager.java:122) ~[mule-module-spring-config-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.applyLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:94) ~[mule-core-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.doApplyLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:87) ~[mule-core-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.doOnTransition(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:68) ~[mule-core-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.lambda$onTransition$0(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:51) ~[mule-core-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.func.CheckedRunnable.run(CheckedRunnable.java:21) ~[mule-core-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
.....
```

I kindly appreciate any insights on this. I know the error is with 'resource::' but if I change anything, it states that no .raml file could be found. I'm thinking it might be a framework bug. I've never seen anyone using an exported API as source for their .raml files in the examples on the internet. They always have the .raml files under src/main/resources/api.

Thank you very much!